# Сколько способов представить число в виде суммы слагаемых. Зная что каждая число из суммы будет меньше предыдущей

Tags: c++

К примеру если число будет 6, то способов будет 4. первый способ это просто 6+0. второй это 5+1, третий 4+2, четвертый 3+2+1.
Мне нужна помощь создать алгоритм который будет считать сколько способов возможных есть.

Comment: если 0 тоже фигурируется, то  бесконечно много

Comment: Как то метка с++ единственное что связывает вопрос и тематику сайта...

Comment: почему бесконечно много то? у меня просто задачка не простая. а я примерный алгоритм забыл.

Comment: 134 = 133 + 1 = 133 + 1 + 0 = 132 +  2 = 132 + 2 + 0 = 131 + 3 = 131 + 3 + 0  = 131  + 2 + 1 =  131 + 2 + 1 + 0 = 130 + 4 = 130 + 4 + 0 = 130 + 3 + 1 = 130 + 3 + 1 + 0 ... так что ли?

Comment: задача немножко по другому. но перевести нормально её я не смог. мне нужен алгоритм где 0 не фигурируется . и просто к ответу который получу от этого алгоритма добавлю 1 и всё .

Comment: Совершенно не понятно, зачем тут фигурирует слагаемое `0`. `5 = 3 + 2` и `5 = 3 + 2 + 0` - это что, считается за два разных разложения?

Comment: Рекомендую: https://oeis.org/A000009 - это и есть искомая последовательность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, условие сформулировано нечетко. Все указывает на то, что слагаемое `0` нас не интересует вообще. Нет никакого смысла рассматривать `6 + 0` вместо просто `6`.

Во-вторых, если ввести в рассмотрение функцию `F(n, s)`, которая возвращает количество разложений числа `n` на суммы, в которых самым первым (максимальным) слагаемым является `s`, то искомое количество разложений числа `N` будет равно

```
F(N, N) + F(N, N - 1) + ... + F(N, 1)
```

Для вычисления `F(n, s)` можно выстроить несложную рекурсивную схему

```
F(n, s) = 
  F(n - s, s - 1) +
  F(n - s, s - 2) +
  ...
  F(n - s, 1)

F(n, s) = 0, при n < s
F(k, k) = 1
```

Эту схему можно оптимизировать, если заметить, что если в какой-то момент в вышеприведенных суммах значение `F(...)` становится равным `0`, то и все последующие слагаемые заведомо будут равны `0`.

Хотя понятно, что такое "решение" без мемоизации является не более чем полным перебором вариантов. Но стоит добавить мемоизацию - и оно уже будет иметь определенный смысл.

Comment: Метод точный, но, скорее всего, есть что-то более хитрое - по крайней мере (с мемоизацией) этот метод у меня работает для 300 чуть больше 6 секунд, в то время как Mathematica дает почти мгновенно, и даже для 1000 - около 3 секунд...